# longitudinal data table in gtsummary

Tags: gtsummary

```
library(data.table)
library(gtsummary)    
mm<-structure(list(time = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 
    2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), meas1 = c(59, 0, 0, 109, 6.8, 0, 98, 
    11, 2.7, 121, 9.9, 0, 136, 63, 22.9, 130, 0, 0, 86, 23, 0), ID = c("001", 
    "001", "001", "002", "002", "002", "003", "003", "003", "004", 
    "004", "004", "005", "005", "005", "006", "006", "006", "007", 
    "007", "007"), gr = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", 
    "A", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -21L), class = c("data.table", 
    "data.frame"))
```

Now, I´d like to generate a table with cells containing the median and IQR for the different levels of group (gr) at each of the different time points.

```
g <- function(x) {
  k <- as.list(quantile(x, (1 : 3) / 4, na.rm=TRUE))
  names(k) <- .q(Q1, Q2, Q3)
  k
}
mm2 <- mm[, g(meas1), by=.(gr, time)]
mm2[,iqr:=paste0(Q2,"(",Q1,"-",Q3,")")]
dcast(mm2,time~gr,value.var = "iqr")
```

Is there an easy way to do this in gtsummary? Preferably without inflating the N in the column header and extra bonus if the range could be with a newline centered on the median?

===================================================================

Edit after including the answer from @Daniel D. Sjoberg

```
tba <- unique(mm$time) %>% 
  sort() %>%
  purrr::map(
    ~ mm %>%
      dplyr::filter(time %in% .x) %>%
      tbl_summary(
        by = gr, 
        include = meas1,
        type = meas1 ~ "continuous2",
        statistic = meas1 ~ c("{median} ({p25}, {p75})", "{min}, {max}"),
        label = list(meas1 = paste("Measure 1 at Timepoint", .x))
      ) 
  ) %>%
  tbl_stack() 

fac <- as.list(as.data.frame(combn(levels(as.factor(mm$gr)),2)))
tbb <- lapply(fac,function(x){
  hh <- mm[gr%in%x]
  unique(hh$time) %>% 
    sort() %>% 
    purrr::map(
      ~hh %>% dplyr::filter(time %in% .x) %>% 
        tbl_summary( by = gr,
                     include = meas1,
                     type = meas1 ~ "continuous2",
                     statistic = meas1 ~ c("{median}","({p25}, {p75})"),
                     label = list(meas1 = paste("Measure 1 at Timepoint", .x))) %>%
        add_difference()) %>% 
    tbl_stack() %>% modify_column_hide(all_stat_cols())
})

tb_b <- tbb %>% tbl_merge(tab_spanner = unlist(lapply(fac,function(x) paste0("**",x[[1]]," vs. ",x[[2]],"**"))))  

tbl_merge(list(tba,tb_b))
```

tba results in desired output:
[image]

tb_b also results in desired output:
[image]

But- when merging these, the spanner from tb_b is lost identifying the contrasts.[image] Any way of that I can retain the original spanners from tb_b when doing tbl_merge?

Also - the add_q helper is likely wrong when doing these stacked tables. Any way of fixing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get multi-row summaries and p-value, you'll need to construct a table for each timepoint, then stack them.

```r
library(data.table)
library(gtsummary)  

mm<-structure(list(time = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 
                            2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), 
                   meas1 = c(59, 0, 0, 109, 6.8, 0, 98, 
                             11, 2.7, 121, 9.9, 0, 136, 63, 22.9, 130, 0, 0, 86, 23, 0), 
                   ID = c("001", 
                          "001", "001", "002", "002", "002", "003", "003", "003", "004", 
                          "004", "004", "005", "005", "005", "006", "006", "006", "007", 
                          "007", "007"), gr = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", 
                                                "A", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"
                          )), row.names = c(NA, -21L), class = c("data.table", 
                                                                 "data.frame"))



unique(mm$time) %>% 
  sort() %>%
  purrr::map(
    ~ mm %>%
      dplyr::filter(time %in% .x) %>%
      tbl_summary(
        by = gr, 
        include = meas1,
        type = meas1 ~ "continuous2",
        statistic = meas1 ~ c("{median} ({p25}, {p75})", "{min}, {max}"),
        label = list(meas1 = paste("Measure 1 at Timepoint", .x))
      ) %>%
      add_p()
  ) %>%
  tbl_stack() %>%
  as_kable() # convert to kable to show on SO
```

| **Characteristic** | **A**, N = 2 | **B**, N = 3 | **C**, N = 2 | **p-value** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Measure 1 at Timepoint 1 |  |  |  | 0.2 |
| Median (IQR) | 78 (69, 88) | 109 (98, 120) | 128 (125, 132) |  |
| Range | 59, 98 | 86, 130 | 121, 136 |  |
| Measure 1 at Timepoint 2 |  |  |  | 0.5 |
| Median (IQR) | 6 (3, 8) | 7 (3, 15) | 36 (23, 50) |  |
| Range | 0, 11 | 0, 23 | 10, 63 |  |
| Measure 1 at Timepoint 3 |  |  |  | 0.4 |
| Median (IQR) | 1.4 (0.7, 2.0) | 0.0 (0.0, 0.0) | 11.4 (5.7, 17.2) |  |
| Range | 0.0, 2.7 | 0.0, 0.0 | 0.0, 22.9 |  |

<sup>Created on 2022-09-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Close—but in reality I have 8 timepoints and would like these to be rowwise rather than having 24 columns in my final table… something like the dcast version —

Comment: Gotcha, I'm not at a computer to give a full solution. But I think the tbl_contimuous() function does exactly what you need

Comment: Indeed--`mm %>% tbl_continuous(by=gr,variable=meas1,include = time) %>% modify_header(all_stat_cols() ~ "**{level}**")` did the trick. Trying to add the IQR on a new line (`mm %>% tbl_continuous(by=gr,variable=meas1,include = time,type=meas1~"continuous2",statistic = meas1 ~ c("{median} ({p25}, {p75})"))`),throws an error since type is not allowed. Likewise - I'd like to give p-values for each time point, not for all time points. Is there anyway I can do that?

Comment: Updated! I think this is what you're after

Comment: Sweet-- That is exactly what I what looking for. But-- I always find other questions. see edit in question

Comment: `tbl_merge(tab_spanner = FALSE)`

Comment: Promise I´ll get off your back, but I was just wondering if there is a function buried deep down in gtsummary allowing changes in the output from add_difference into one column rather than three to save space with superscripted stars indicating significance, i.e. 2.5 (1.2, 3.8)**

Comment: You can merge columns with modify_column_merge()

Comment: for completeness:`tbl_merge(list(tba,tb_b),tab_spanner = FALSE) %>% modify_column_merge(pattern="{estimate_1_2}, ({ci_1_2}); p={p.value_1_2}",rows = !is.na(estimate_1_2)) %>% 
  modify_column_merge(pattern="{estimate_2_2}, ({ci_2_2}); p={p.value_2_2}",rows = !is.na(estimate_2_2)) %>% 
  modify_column_merge(pattern="{estimate_3_2}, ({ci_3_2}); p={p.value_3_2}",rows = !is.na(estimate_3_2))` gave me what I wanted in the end apart from the asterixed p-values. But impressive functionality nonetheless--

Comment: For the moment, p-value starts are only available in regression model summaries. But will soon be more widely available. You can follow here for the progress on being made available in all gtsummary tables. can you tell me where you want the stars?  do people just add them onto the p-value?

https://github.com/ddsjoberg/gtsummary/issues/1320

Comment: I often see that p<0.001 is denoted***, <0.01**. and<0.05* superscripted and after the confidence interval- 4, (3, 6)*** -- improves legibility in tables with many numbers.

Comment: Hey hey @Misha, Can you check out the updated `add_significance_stars()` function? Does it meet your needs?
https://github.com/ddsjoberg/gtsummary/issues/1320 

https://github.com/ddsjoberg/gtsummary/pull/1338

Comment: Hey @Daniel - Thanks reg %>% tbl_regression %>% add_significance_stars(pattern="{estimate} ({ci}){stars}") gives the form I was looking for. However, I was hoping that the add function would include tbl_summary objects and the p-values as well. But I guess it could be hacked quite easily from the add_difference function.

Comment: The update (that still lives in the pull request branch) works on any gtsummary table that includes a p-value column, so it will also work with `tbl_summary() %>% add_difference()`. I think I am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to recommend MicrobiomeStat for your microbiome data analysis needs. MicrobiomeStat provides a user-friendly and efficient way to analyze microbiome time series data, making it a great alternative to q2-longitudinal in R. With MicrobiomeStat, you can easily perform longitudinal and paired sample comparisons, visualize your data, and obtain meaningful insights. Give it a try and simplify your microbiome research! #MicrobiomeResearch #DataAnalysis